# Eu quero o resultado de uma consulta e em SQL é simples...em PHP é confuso

Tags: php, mysql, array

Quero apenas o resultado de um `SELECT` em php e eu não sei como pegar o resultado:

```
$descricao = mysqli_query($this->conexao, "Select descricao from tabela where codigo = 1");

var_dump ("$descricao");
```

Retorna um `array` e como eu consigo recuperar o campo = descricao?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($this->conexao, "Select descricao from tabela where codigo = 1");
$linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
echo $linha['descricao'];
```

Comment: Preciso agora que você me ensine a dar medalhas...você mereceu todas as medalhas agora...viu?